# Simple circular linked list in c

Tags: c

I am implementing a simple circular linked list.

There was a problem during the test while still implementing the insertion function.

According to the code I implemented below,

The output I expected was 10 20, but the result is 20 20.

I can't figure out what's wrong even if I fixed it a few times.

Is this the wrong approach from the beginning?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct node
{
    element data;
    struct node *link;
} *nodePointer;
typedef struct list
{
    nodePointer *head;
    int length;
}listPointer;

nodePointer *head = NULL;
listPointer *list = NULL;

void createList()
{
    list = (listPointer *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->length = 0;
}
void insertLast(element data)
{
    printf("here %d\n", data);
    nodePointer newNode = (nodePointer)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        newNode->link = newNode;
        head = &newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->link = (*head)->link;
        (*head)->link = newNode;
    }
    list->head = head;
    printf("%d\n", (*head)->data);
    list->length++;
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    nodePointer printNode = (*list->head);
    for(i = 0; i <list->length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", printNode->data);
        printNode = printNode->link;
    }
    puts("");
}
int main(void)
{
    createList();
    insertLast(10);
    insertLast(20);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `listPointer` isn't a pointer. And `head` is a pointer-to-a-pointer. This code is a good demonstration of why you should never `typedef` a pointer.

Comment: `head = newNode`.  `&newNode` is the address of the pointer, not the node.

Comment: This code segfaults for me. Is this the exact code that produces `20 20`?

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Probably completely unrelated, but `insertLast` appears to insert a node between the head of the list, and the next node, instead of inserting it onto the end of the list.

Comment: Why do you have a global `head` variable? That seems to be completely useless, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would clean your code up a bit. For example, `listPointer` doesn't refer to a pointer, but to a struct. Also, `head` refers to a double-pointer, which seems unnecessary. Also, it is a bad idea to typdef a pointer, as some people have pointed out in the comments. Lastly, `insertLast` doesn't actually apend an item onto the list, but simply inserts the item in the position after `head`. This is what I got after cleaning up a bit, and it works perfectly. Honestly, I'm not exactly sure what went wrong, but here is some working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct node
{
    element data;
    struct node *link;
} node;
typedef struct list
{
    node *head;
    int length;
} llist;

node *head = NULL;
llist *list = NULL;

void createList()
{
    list = (llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->length = 0;
}
void insertLast(element data)
{
    printf("here %d\n", data);
    node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        newNode->link = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
        {
        node *lastNode = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < list->length; i++) {
            lastNode = lastNode->link;
        }

        lastNode->link = newNode;
    }
    list->head = head;
    printf("%d\n", head->data);
    list->length++;
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    node *printNode = list->head;
    for(i = 0; i < list->length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", printNode->data);
        printNode = printNode->link;
    }
    puts("");
}
int main(void)
{
    createList();
    insertLast(10);
    insertLast(20);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: so helpful answer, Thanks a lot!